# Lifecycle Hook for after ngModel is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a function that I need to run after `this.value` is set in my component. I tried using the lifecycle hook `ngAfterContentInit()` but `this.value` is either null or an empty string at that point.

I'm referencing my component like:

```
<add-select name="address" [options]="knownAddresses" [(ngModel)]="user.address"></add-select>
```

And my component looks like

```
const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddSelect),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'add-select',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/add-select/add-select.html',
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class AddSelect implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() options: any[];

  // * NEED THIS TO RUN AFTER this.value IS CURRENT WHICH IS PASSED IN VIA ngModel
  private syncModelAndOptions() {
        if (this.options && this.value) {
            const modelOption = _.find(this.options, option => {
                return item == this.value || (option._id && this.value._id && option._id === this.value._id);
            });

            if (modelOption) {
                this.value = modelOption;
            } else {
                this.options.push(this.value);
            }
        }
    }

  //get accessor
  get value(): any {
    ...
  };

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    ...
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  writeValue(value: any) {
    ...
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    ...
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use AfterViewChecked lifecycle to get the ngModel when it HAS an actual value. If you really want to use lifecycle hooks.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview

But... You should use ngModelChange as it Is an ngModel event.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html (search for ngModelChange)

Comment: I'm certainly not fixed on the lifecycle hook, I just thought that was the way I should do this. If I use the lifecycle event it works, but I'd rather do something a bit more efficient if possible. I only need the fn to run once after  `this.value` is actually defined. Even if I pass in a value, it's still undefined until later. Is the lifecycle hook the only way to do what I need?

Comment: DId you check the ngModelChange? It should run every time model changes.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't fire when the initial value is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface is so that your component would play nicely with Angular forms (both template-driven and reactive).

In template-driven forms (that's basically when you use `ngModel`), an update to `ngModel` eventually triggers a call to `ControlValueAccessor.writeValue`, which is supposed to know how to update the underlying form controls.

So a surefire way to run something as soon as `this.value` is set by the framework (i.e. `ngModel`) is to call it from within `writeValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using NgModel this way would help you. Inside your Component:

```
  import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

    /*...*/

  constructor(ngModel: NgModel) {

    ngModel.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('ngModel set')
    });
  }
```